# How would i get the value of HTTP response

Tags: json, parsing, post, asp-classic, httpwebresponse

This is the response, https://www.viewmyrecord.com/Texting/GetReply.asp?from=15621234567&to=15629876543&text=Hi Kid,Reminder November 22, 2019 w/ REN.

How would i get the value of "from","to" and "text" and save it to a textfile

```
    <%
      If Request.TotalBytes > 0 Then
        Dim lngBytesCount
        lngBytesCount = Request.TotalBytes
        Response.Write BytesToStr(Request.BinaryRead(lngBytesCount))
        response.Clear

    dim fs,tfile,loc,locadd,loctime,loctime1,nameFile,datename

    datDate = Now()
    locadd = Trim(FormatDateTime(datDate, 1)) 
    loctime = FormatDateTime(datDate, 4)
    loctime1 =  stripNonNumeric(FormatDateTime(Now, 3))
    nameFile = "E:\Rhy Files\api\"
    datename = Trim(loctime1&"-"&locadd&".txt")
    loc = "E:\Rhy Files\api\"&loctime1&"-"&locadd&".txt"
    set fs=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    set tfile=fs.CreateTextFile(loc)
    tfile.WriteLine(try)
    tfile.close
    set tfile=nothing
    set fs=nothing

    Dim objExe

    Dim sResult

    Set objExe = Server.CreateObject("ASPExec.Execute")

    objExe.Application = "C:\Windows\System32\try.exe"

    objExe.Parameters = "E:\Rhy Files\api\AA.txt "&datename&""  '*** Parameter ***'

    objExe.ShowWindow = False

    sResult = objExe.ExecuteWinApp

    set fs=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    set tfile=fs.CreateTextFile("E:\Rhy Files\api\Try.txt")
    tfile.WriteLine(loc)
    tfile.close
    set tfile=nothing
    set fs=nothing

    End If

    Function BytesToStr(bytes)
        Dim Stream
        Set Stream = Server.CreateObject("Adodb.Stream")
            Stream.Type = 1 'adTypeBinary
            Stream.Open
            Stream.Write bytes
            Stream.Position = 0
            Stream.Type = 2 'adTypeText
            Stream.Charset = "iso-8859-1"
            BytesToStr = Stream.ReadText
            try = BytesToStr

            Stream.Close
        Set Stream = Nothing
    End Function

    Response.write(Request.QueryString)

    Function stripNonNumeric(inputString)
        Set regEx = New RegExp
         regEx.Global = True
         regEx.Pattern = "\D"
         stripNonNumeric = regEx.Replace(inputString,"")
      End Function
    %>
```

Thank you so much in advance, i am new with this so i really need your help guys.:)

Comment: Architecturally there are some things wrong here that make it difficult to answer. For example it is more likely that you'd call something like https://www.viewmyrecord.com/Texting/GetReply.asp?ID=12345  and your response would be returned as the content of the HTTP request which would contain the to, from, and text. If I'm mistaken there could you provide more information about what URL you call to arrive at the one you posted?

Comment: The three fields you want should be `request.querystring("from")`, `request.querystring("to")`, and `request.querystring("text")`, respectively